# Starting a fresh micronaut app on my machine gives io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException

Tags: gradle, micronaut

I am trying to run this micronaut app newly on my computer. Note that it works fine on the other peers that are cloning the same application from our local git repo. What is surprising is that the error bean is not being referenced anywhere in the codebase. This is the error when I start `./gradlew run`. Tried deleting everything from `~/.gradle/caches` but to no avail.

```
    12:35:55.928 [main] ERROR  [,]   io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Error starting Micronaut server: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.management.health.indicator.service.ServiceReadyHealthIndicator$ApplicationEventListener$onServerStarted2$Intercepted]: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Error instantiating bean of type [io.micronaut.management.health.indicator.service.ServiceReadyHealthIndicator$ApplicationEventListener$onServerStarted2$Intercepted]: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2267)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.addCandidateToList(DefaultBeanContext.java:3601)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanRegistrations(DefaultBeanContext.java:3477)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeansOfType(DefaultBeanContext.java:856)
        at io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisherFactory$2.lambda$$0(ApplicationEventPublisherFactory.java:217)
        at io.micronaut.core.util.SupplierUtil$2.initialize(SupplierUtil.java:77)
        at io.micronaut.core.util.SupplierUtil$2.get(SupplierUtil.java:72)
        at io.micronaut.context.event.ApplicationEventPublisherFactory$2.publishEvent(ApplicationEventPublisherFactory.java:229)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.publishEvent(DefaultBeanContext.java:1650)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.fireStartupEvents(NettyHttpServer.java:560)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.start(NettyHttpServer.java:403)
        at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.NettyHttpServer.start(NettyHttpServer.java:155)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.lambda$start$2(Micronaut.java:77)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.start(Micronaut.java:75)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:311)
        at io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.run(Micronaut.java:297)
        at com.iss.datadesk.reportapi.Application.main(Application.java:17)
Caused by: io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found: [io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry, io.micronaut.aop.InterceptorRegistry]
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:2331)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultApplicationContext.java:451)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.lastChanceResolve(DefaultBeanContext.java:3165)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidateNoCache(DefaultBeanContext.java:3052)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.findConcreteCandidate(DefaultBeanContext.java:2966)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBeanInternal(DefaultBeanContext.java:2652)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:824)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:205)
        at io.micronaut.aop.chain.InterceptorChain.resolveIntroductionInterceptors(InterceptorChain.java:144)
        at io.micronaut.management.health.indicator.service.ServiceReadyHealthIndicator$ApplicationEventListener$onServerStarted2$Intercepted.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.management.health.indicator.service.$ServiceReadyHealthIndicator$ApplicationEventListener$onServerStarted2$Intercepted$Definition.build(Unknown Source)
        at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.doCreateBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:2238)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Would you be able to point out to a reference to your application sources?

Comment: try gradlew clean build